# bootstrap CSS Image Gallery Autoplay

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have small problem on my web site : http://79.115.10.208:5000/product/34b78898-9151-46a7-8f61-56ff5fa8171c.html

If you select 2 image and after a select the first, hide all! I'm try change all, whiteout solve problem. the css is bootstrap, whit jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is your problem:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <div id="mini_img_produs">

    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.29223794-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.75299351-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.08105532-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.01723726-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>

  </div>
</ol>
```

Bootstrap adds `active` class to your div with id of `mini_img_produs`. You have to delete this div. `li` items have to be direct children of the `ul`.

Change code to:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">

  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.29223794-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.75299351-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.08105532-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" class=""><img src="/static/uploads/27/thumb.01723726-am-pula-mare.jpg" width="111" height="80"></li>

</ol>
```